# Horizontally Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm developing a new RDLC chart report in Visual Studio 2012, and I'd want it to look similar to the report [here](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&tbo=d&biw=1920&bih=979&tbm=isch&tbnid=uZ99WySJgD1hcM%3a&imgrefurl=http://support2.dundas.com/onlinedocumentation/webchart2005/dcStacked_Column_Chart.html&docid=EWW6NLQkMYcv8M&imgurl=http://support2.dundas.com/onlinedocumentation/webchart2005/ChartType_Images/StackedColumnChart.png&w=404&h=326&ei=owv_UOK3EuuM0QGrr4DIBQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=436&sig=100790038594854775489&page=1&tbnh=134&tbnw=166&start=0&ndsp=51&ved=1t:429,r:3,s:0,i:94&tx=83&ty=91).

I see lots of different types of available charts in Visual Studio, but I don't see a stacked bar chart.  Is this simply missing from Visual Studio 2012, or am I just not seeing it?  Ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish is displaying percentage values in a horizontally stacked bar chart.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it -- (Select Chart Type --> Bar --> 100% Stacked Bar).  It was right in front of me!